# Need help for hyperref driver modification

Tags: hyperref, html

**Question:** When hyperref generates a link, this link can start in the middle of a line, may comprise several lines and then can end in the middle of a line. I need the starting and ending positions in all three cases and for all the involved rectangular areas. It would be great if I could write them to a file in some format where I also have information on the affected link.

**Background:** I need to build an HTML layer which overlays a PNG image which was produced from a LaTeX file with suitable HTML links. For this, I need to know where the HTML link should start, where it should end and which URL is affected.

**Attempts:** I have tried to pickup positions using zref. This works fine but has two disadvantages: First, it only works when the entire link stays within one line. Second, it needs to LaTeX runs. What I am searching for is some hook into or modification of the hyperref driver where this information is available and could be written out to a file immediately. However, I do not manage to understand the hyperref code...

Comment: hyperref doesn't know the coordinates, it only calls a primitive (\pdfstartlink in the case of pdftex) which then calculates the coordinates.

Comment: Hm. Maybe hyperref is the wrong question then. But somebody knows the parameters, since in the generated pdf there is one rectangular annotation for every part of the link.

Comment: well the engine knows the parameters. There is a whatsits at the place where the link starts and when the page is written this is used. But basically this is what savepos does too.

Comment: Any chance to access the other points? My problem is that I only get the first point of the first line and the last point of the last line - and nothing in between.